# Never ask to reset password ever after created from azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have created users in bulk (around 100) in Azure Active Directory and would like to use those users in my automation test on a microsoft product.

Problem is - when for the very first time user tries to login , I'm asked to reset the password. Which I want to avoid.

Is there a way using az command connecting to AAD and make changes such that I'm not asked to reset the password.

I tried to automate the reset password process but - facing some issue.

I have tried below command to never expire the password but this wont help me here.

Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Set-AzureADUser -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration

Comment: I was looking for single command which does for all users available may be under a group -However what you suggested serves the purpose. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the AAD domain to which the user belongs has an appropriate password expiration policy, you will be asked to change your password when you log in for the first time.

My method is to set `-ForceChangePasswordNextLogin` to `false`, and then when the user logs in for the first time, you will not be asked to reset the password.

`Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId <String>  -ForceChangePasswordNextLogin $false`

[image]